# Does Verilog `ifdef respond to environment variables?

Tags: macros, system-verilog, conditional-compilation

If I have the following Verilog code:

```
//test.v

`ifdef V1
{code block 1}
`else
{code block 2}
`endif
```

can I "steer" the conditional from the command line, using standard environment variable definition syntax?
For instance, would this cause {code block 1} to execute?:

```
$ V1=1 <simulator> test.v
```

Comment: no, verilog simulator is not supposed to recognize environment variables. Depending on the simulator, you might be able to define verilog macros at the command line. The exact way depends on the implementation of the simulator. Consult with the simulator documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The `ifdef` statement is a compiler directive much like a preprocessor directive in C or C++ so you can pass them through the command line in a similar way using the `-D$var` flag.

Let's say we have the following module:

```
// test.v

module hello;
  initial 
    begin
`ifdef V1
      $display("V1 defined!");
`else
      $display("V1 not defined!");
`endif
      $finish ;
    end
endmodule
```

Then using IcarusVerilog for example you can define `V1` on the command line using:

```
terminal:~$ iverilog -DV1 -o test test.v
terminal:~$ vvp test
V1 defined!
terminal:~$ iverilog -o test test.v
terminal:~$ vvp test
V1 not defined!
```